# Spring Batch multiple jobs at once started?

Tags: spring-batch

In my spring batch i see following logs.

```
INFO 5572 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=sample]] launched with the following parameters: [{JobID=x}]
INFO 5572 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=sample]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1, JobID=y}]
INFO 5572 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
INFO 5572 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
```

Is this same log lines repeated by two threads or two jobs started at once ?

Comment: I added an answer to your question. Did it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your logs, two different job instances are executed by two different threads: `scheduling-1` and `main`.

Comment: Yes there are two threads running. Apparently spring batch start job on application start and i have separate spring scheduler.